# Find domain originating the request in fastify server

Tags: node.js, fastify

In express we can access it like

```
var origin = req.get('origin');
```

How do we achieve the same in fastify server?

What have I tried so far: I know that fastify allows us to access `request.id`. But I am looking to find the domain. I have also tried reading the `hostname` parameter, but it is the hostname of the server([www.local-demo.com:8080](http://www.local-demo.com:8080)).

How do find the domain originating the request.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the [express documentation](https://expressjs.com/it/4x/api.html#req.get), `req.get('origin')` reads the HTTP `origin` header.

So, to do the same with Fastify you need to write:

```js
const httpHeader = request.headers.origin
```

*As reminder: all the HTTP Headers are lower case*

Comment: Somehow for fastify server, `request.headers.origin` value is undefined. `request.headers` gives me access to `host`, `connection`, `accept` and `cookie` only.

Comment: Are you executing the same `curl` request to both servers? I may think that the express app has some middleware that lookup that information from other sources.